# How to connect User and Address Model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model

I was trying to connect two models one default User Model and another Address Model in Laravel but I am having some trouble connecting these two.

User Model is as

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Address;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Address');
    }
}
```

And Address Model is

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;
use Session;

class Address extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'usercontacts';
    public function address()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

How does this properly work? Any tips will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Good starting point , https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

First off, based on the way you are defining the relationship, do you have a column in your `usercontacts`'s table called `user_id`?

If not, you would need one. Or if you are using some other specific foreign key such as, say, `belongs_to_user_id`, you have to specify that as the second argument in the `hasOne` relationship. E.g.

```
// User.php
return $this->hasOne('App\Address', 'belongs_to_user_id');
```

Can you share the error messages you are getting with us?

Comment: Usercontacts table has user_id but no value is returned to that column, I have another post and category relationship which works fine. I think the problem is that User model extends Authenticatable not Model

Answer (score 0):

on the Address model change the 
public function address(){
......
}

**TO**

public function **users**(){
.....
}